# getting contents with tinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, wysiwyg

I have a tinyMCE textarea #frmbody and am using the jquery instance of it.

```
<textarea class="tinymce" name="frmbody" id="frmbody" cols="30" rows="20"></textarea>
```

I'm trying to get the contents of the textarea as the user types.

```
$("#frmbody").live('keyup', function(e) {
    alert("keyup");
});
```

The code above is not working and I'm not sure why.  If I remove the tinyMCE instance, the code above works fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: Don't know, but chances are tinyMCE creates (or re-creates) a different textarea in which you actually type, so `#frmbody` never has any key activity.

Comment: I was thinking that, too.  I'll keep digging and searching.  Thanks

Comment: The only other thing though is when i check the $_POST values, frmbody is there.

Comment: tinyMCE hides your textarea and handles all the typing itself.  When the form posts, it copies the created HTML back into your textarea.  However, it has a large variety of its own events you can hook into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because an instance of TinyMCE isn't a true textarea, so keyup events aren't detected. Try the [onchange callback](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aonchange_callback) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can make tinyMCE own listener by:
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:event.tinymce.Editor.onKeyUp

or write your own and use built-in function getContent:
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.getContent

Answer (score 1):

One could just grab the contents of the editor using :

```
tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
```

If you want to attach an onchange event, according to this page, http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:class.tinymce.Editor, create the editor using the following code :

```
var ed = new tinymce.Editor('textarea_id', { 
    init_setting_item: 1,
    ...
}, tinymce.EditorManager);

ed.on('change', function(e) {
    var content = ed.getContent();
    $("#textarea_id").val(content); // update the original textarea with the content
    console.log(content);
});

ed.render();
```

Please note that onchange is fire when the user unfocuses, press enter, or press a toolbar button instead of every keystroke.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to write an own handler and assign it to the editor iframe document.
There are tinymce handlers for various events already defined like [keyUp](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3aevent.tinymce.Editor.onKeyUp)

Here is the standard way to assign an own handler to the editor iframe document

```
var my_handler = function(event) {
    alert('my handler fired!');
};

var ed = tinymce.get('my_editor_id');
$(ed.getDoc()).bind('keyup', my_handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE hides the Text Area and creates a html container. If you write content in the box its a iFrame with the name `"TEXTAREANAME_ifr"`.

So try this:

```
$("#frmbody_ifr").live('keyup', function(e) {
    alert("keyup");
});
```

I think as Thariama already said the EventHandler from TinyMCE would be the best way.