# Observe changes in TinyMCE from Dart

Tags: tinymce, dart, dart-js-interop

According to [TinyMCE API](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:event.tinymce.Editor.onChange), the following JavaScript code observe changes in TinyMCE editor:

```js
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
          ed.onChange.add(function(ed, l) {
                  console.debug('Editor contents was modified. Contents: ' + l.content);
          });
   }
});
```

However, I'm unable to run this code from Dart using the js Library. Help is appreciated.

UPDATE:
There is a problem in the JS code above. Alternatively, I found this working code in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17002990/2159066):

```js
var ed = new tinymce.Editor('textarea_id', { 
  init_setting_item: 1,
}, tinymce.EditorManager);

ed.on('change', function(e) {
  var content = ed.getContent();
  console.log(content);
});

ed.render();
```

I still need help running the code from Dart. And preferably storing its results in a Dart variable for subsequent processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the same code called from Dart :

```dart
var ed = new js.Proxy(js.context.tinymce.Editor, 'textarea_id', js.map({ 
  'init_setting_item': 1
}), js.context.tinymce.EditorManager);

js.retain(ed); // retain allows to use 'ed' in the following callback
ed.on('change', new js.Callback.many((e) {
  var content = ed.getContent();
  window.console.log(content);
}));

ed.render();
```

Comment: I get no error now. But nothing gets outputted to the console. Thanks.

Comment: I've just checked. The equivalent js code is not working. Unfortunately, I don't know js so I'm not able to find the source of the problem.

Comment: This JS code works: 
**var ed = new tinymce.Editor('writepad', {init_setting_item: 1,}, tinymce.EditorManager); ed.on('change', function(e) {var content = ed.getContent(); console.log(content);}); ed.render();**

Comment: Alexandre. Now I get this error in Dartium console: Uncaught Proxy js-ref-7 has been invalidated.
f
fire tinymce.min.js:8
a.add tinymce.min.js:6
o tinymce.min.js:6
(anonymous function) tinymce.min.js:6
fire tinymce.min.js:8
(anonymous function) tinymce.min.js:8
i tinymce.min.js:2
m tinymce.min.js:2

Comment: I've added **js.retain(ed);** before the last line above and the code works. Thank you Alexandre for your help and patience. Best.

Comment: Oops, I missed the `js.retain`. Sorry.

Comment: This started to show in my editor: There is no such getter 'tinymce' in 'Proxy'. Do you know what is going wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: Please update your `js` package. The warning should disappear.

Comment: The warning has gone from Dart code after updating my js package. But, running the code as javascript displays the same error warning in the console: "Warning: No member named 'tinymce' in class 'Proxy'".

Comment: This is the first error: "...packages/js/js.dart:990:11: Hint: The class 'Proxy' overrides 'operator==', but not 'get hashCode'. operator==(other) => identical(this, other)"